# How to get polkadot's transaction and transfer at json rpc

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc, polkadot

I testing at westend(polkadot testnet) use json-rpc

How can I extract transaction and etc from extrinsis and check it?

https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#getblockhash-blockhash-signedblock

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"chain_getBlock", "params":["BlockHash"],"id":1 }'
```

response

```
{"block": { 
"extrinsics": [ "0x280402000be1da78d37e01",     "0xd91f042d00401401000000001a6bb010c80ee356a801602fe9e28ff820f548a982312ee737dd15c85aead002687d4d83396efca5c145bca092834af45b6652512b06dc78b46bc52a3659fa83140101000000f0f8063ff5a2e8592347a2c11cd87d9e4ddfd7a5b93915e5492d36b79bd47648ac35ba1b7be83f7feedafbd0934c500521787a2b3a370d5f3aec1d9bf4baa38c1401020000005420cd14e1341f1eacf6d4bd19902c94e3af4441f3365db0420b635bae95235925f9046c84c7db838115573a7e745f380effa6f2aca3252611f8a52f7d7a29871401030000002e7b5ba51e269894a2d3a0f54f0a090a40d0de1ef9be6c2efa18d651f3465c547c184222851d0b72491a02d753a022ec2818ce8ed34cedd591fc0e4b86ca218c140104000000427d3becde96c713a4ef59c960e13ec5a8d0657d1214fdb24c56fc8f58f3293c8e9cd226583fee171561ad9c6a9812e311226cdf0fa44cc20db19aa2ee723e831401050000009c2b5da735b2e7d2f055e398780a8ede9309cb4bcccfa6665d30fba608a0cb6d00bf689db57242eedd438b2731497dec2484b0875e4bbc087ad2f55a4eed548a1401060000008e2d5a62d5cdda14bceb7c5a350dc2cc4125d0045f92f266bacd1c254785dd1525cbcd7605d1662991c30a706eb93351f795a5788cb136b9ede7200a2b6c288c140107000000746dd12921ddebfec87b4728aaf876870efe71c87e84907312ae992d7760fc686588068b92d448aaa314247323d760524fc59b2b5f4d714b11e613e57459ca8914010800000080878a3bec69850c7169a481f695b0d6ec3493e135a43ee5326b2707dbab4d59277c48da2e4fcbe545fefbc53de079f9ed907f24564c779c2deac2bcd89d4f8e14010900000014b71d48a4693da625dd709b5feed2d3f04f78f5eb40c932810dfd62d3af83638dbace4183ab8bc3067e8c5d8e82c1d8e870f52846392310d00189adec07b28d14010a0000005a83aa5e22bc75ff6cc66abd4a794d32459002702edbb2082266226852bd6a7bb257fa5b25286e8637f700b0d54e8c7cafcfe1dbbc98497ee1b852774605908d14010b000000deffb1ce2b547366b7fbb641db3ff98876611f3e920fbb9033eeed7acb859a04b3c24ea78841b4aaceb1d6a5e6deb5e0bb6ae0714b5eaa473b05765ed5157c8f14010c0000008299d03ca286f18e88e6d12ef23103700946b9a8a4e6806371a9473db04718298da1dd7f3db4d6c4fb4b8b4c6a5293f418108425ba30b50e761ec75c38caa28814010d00000072fcd84d7c7101e61f3031916b8911c88fe6933a3130528dd2a600c334f1955407f712c7683145018532cd9a5c646ecf0c5ba5104a1556b79a16d320a528d18d14010e000000181dbef7d3770317cadd65b825805cafe5dffe0f321dfc9b529842ebeafc2d35686b219b8d6ce86b0c3addfeb9fe245fa768f5544cd6b008a7375704586c5a8b14010f000000aea5c7442a39db454c9bcd7b1b83b0e6d0828eb8f0dc0693d0f8fd875b43c32d7608b5187782fd76e8fefe43c0cf024e73077a270e5ce3fb5409912d1d15388e04e9030000fdf27e9f1fd499ce9d312e5a7f60e88d06c506287c239bbdcfc9b3738a62c9f99c4a52f73dada2812d6843883b11e2c9210fcf9e093d3c70f44915b189d29159b239c4eec41a44c56054e5ee84472f4bd0a2a4fbbf8d8b3698ac647da7f9cf55402cc300a335ce4bf75dfbc8dbdfd5c6a751cd2b8235f6a128e4b7bb045b3170bcca143638a92149094c99362dbfae7a48fe6cdba889a6afa8474100fcdd77526c4a2fc779a56e6407ce148fb62b93766fa3e6e04c029556d6efc0074c9e83079f8dd8b5c1cfee99f50882e0616a1b41c64c64fa45ae81a70a78976fb83de08c390da23d6b6a0fc494f0d0c1f39f4df50f445815bea20792a9c09156fb075146f55507166fde3facca62f3aa6afca407575f4fe4bb551f7ca34d744c51f3a449000000e9023e0a1d9cefa6802f310b15b7d051630bb14b32598693c16856b2274abcaee602fe411e0016ae13ca9ccdbbf179f19fe39406882c694fa462512153b7e6410263ecec91db0a9858281824b47073941f2f995df3fd5f926003525eb0be77ad040acb72e36408066175726120a0bd2a080000000005617572610101c6c6e414428a0f7008535b8f3c210db91f83b4bfbba625880126a553433bc86d29e506280911770eb2dcec41ce7d9325c2f6c475c2a166f135abddb20c79c48700000000044e90000801c0018a180e681913ae9188ae7fc3675b1d5aff3b00281148d295ba7cceaa742449971fa0518e7f459bfaf54d7f4d9a0f54c14c3eb6b78f39929d27950b85f78202d0cd5b9df0527c9eb7951707d1bdf4fb09a80421a51b46c1dd18004600b1f44150f83bd1136d4c2f10701da7edd70ad22fa549f6aaef3be27936afe32967ba8c0c03007558ba642f453ddfe49fb888c27e2d181bfe29946f6bb7f64b755331e49461b012384102382051028e7ddaa12a120405bf9c7b7a956140ea07ab7d5f02c2c2d83077326b852a6b579ca7bbc1eb2f1dde3d3afb17650f21357517424cb87a450debfacff3080642414245b5010308000000417b551000000000ea5c8ce57aed643bdd6863a59ba4997842d4998c5d3a70452b5ac57f11d2b53484a5a4d4db26d5b1891c8b48dfbdfd614586989fdca4f00be2d7cad1b60b430040e23301a772481b46def0649a5813fb43199aefc856751f07d281905da2f90e05424142450101f62d0cb832fd292a38e50bd07570d36e922b4991922b4b5ebc5831fc41574f7d37ca591f9a4cd4ee80fbb91d06055274e80932f2d826ba24b2c2b7e5b4dca580"
],
"header": {
  "digest": {
    "logs": [
      "0x0642414245b5010305000000427b551000000000888493239316bb8a345f4712486de708aaaab935a754d49146da3f67466bc03132afee2bdb6c792a6fc343efba706e255a203a69ef3fc7896999196360889607880ffc042a635f463e2520146e0afde3591be104e5adc9146da6de0e8c049505",
      "0x054241424501017e8b20b09ea880e3b54a600a2cf451c87a2cd117a03c74fdb41383f043bfeb4a2816e0be57999060946764e0e031588badcc349b436879536c3756c9b161de87"
    ]
  },
  "extrinsicsRoot": "0x264d4ee5030a330b79b43b71d0d2ac503123a984b32082642355cf96ecfc09ed",
  "number": "0x904e05",
  "parentHash": "0xfdf27e9f1fd499ce9d312e5a7f60e88d06c506287c239bbdcfc9b3738a62c9f9",
  "stateRoot": "0xef4a702a0043e5cb5d7daa3569092fbd07f041fb5ced4cff5724981a5c721751"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The transactions are encoded with scale encoding. The answer depends on which language your coding in.

I would use a client library related to your language. https://docs.substrate.io/v3/integration/client-libraries/

(There's also tools like https://github.com/paritytech/subxt which could help.)